# Getting started with Kermit - Basic script

Tags: serial-port, minicom, kermit

I'm new to Kermit (and pretty unexperienced with this kind of programs).

I've got two linux computers which are connected via RS-232 serial interface. The connection works, when I open minicom on both of them, I am able to write on the other interface.

Next step would be to add a connection via Kermit because I want to send files through the interface. I've got a lot of questions how kermit basically works and the documentation is not really helping me out because tbh I don't really understand most of it and it doesn't start at my point of knowledge.

First of all, what do I have to open on the receiving machine? Also Kermit or Minicom?

I tried something like this:

```
set speed 19200           

set line /dev/ttyUSB0

# Connect to the other computer using minicom

echo Connecting to the other computer...

set carrier-watch off

set flow-control none

connect

echo "Hello, this is a test message." > /dev/ttyUSB0

echo Message sent. Closing connection...

bye
```

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to get this working. At the moment, I get this error:

```
?SET SPEED has no effect without prior SET LINE

Sorry, you must SET LINE or SET HOST first
```

Which I don't really understand cause I'm setting the line (its the correct port of the receiving machine).

I looked for basic tutorials but didn't find any so if you know one, would be great, too!

Thanks in advance,

Johannes